# angular loading main route instead of specified route

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I am using $routeProvider in my Angular app. I have 8 different routes. When I type in the browser

> http://localhost:3000/#/signUp

It loads my main route

> http://localhost:3000/#/

and then I have to add signUp manually to the URL

Any idea why it is loading the main route instead of the route specified?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you provide the list of your route?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/claudia1201/552hezuh/

Comment: it looks ok. Do you have ng-view in yout html?

Comment: Yes, I do have and ng-view

Answer (score -1):

try to edit like this:

```
$routeProvider.when("/", {
      templateUrl: "templates/landingPage.html",
    });

$routeProvider.when("/signUp", {
      templateUrl: 'templates/signInView.html',
      controller:"PageController"
});
```

Comment: Just tried it, the main route is the only one loading. It wouldn't load any other routes.

Comment: can you provide  the view?